# @DbLookup in lotusnotes

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus-formula

would somebody help me on this to understand what it is, i am not really getting what it is,

tried a lot but could not arrive at conclusion,

```
@DbLookup ( "" : "NoCache" ; "" ;  "IT-MTBP Info" ; Prt1_ProjNo ; 15 )
```

Thanks a lot and Best Regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the Lotus Notes help:

> @DbLookup( class : cache ; server : database ; view ; key ; fieldName ; keywords ) or
>
> @DbLookup( class : cache ; server : database ; view ; key ; columnNumber ; keywords)

Which means you have:

1. "" : "NoCache" - This doesn't concern you right now
2. Second parameter is empty, so you are searching the **current database**
3. **"IT-MTBP Info"** is the name (or alias) of the view you are searching
4. You are searching for all values matching the **contents** of the field (or variable?) named **Prt1_ProjNo**
5. This call will return the contents of the **15th column** from view "IT-MTBP Info" for all matching documents

Here is the Example page from Lotus Notes Designer help: [LINK](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/rnext/help6_designer.nsf/f4b82fbb75e942a6852566ac0037f284/d359a1c44b37b0a385256c54004bfb7f?OpenDocument)

Hope this helps. If you still have questions you have to ask more specifically.

edit: fixed editing

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed explanations, how can i find this `IT-MTBP Info` name in lotus notes

Comment: Go look at your list of Views in the database design.